# Using light events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, light-sensor

I am confused by the documentation I'm reading here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_Light_Events

How do I get the light intensity of the event?

Answer (score 2):

DeviceLightEvent.value will tell you this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceLightEvent.value